# on relation between upper central series and lower central series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Let $G$ be finite p-group of nilpotency class n and $d(G)=2$ with cyclic center $Z(G)=\langle z\rangle$ and $Z_2(G)$ is non-cyclic abelian group of order $p^3$
I want to understand relation between upper central series and lower central series
I know because class of $G$ is n then $Z_n(G)=G$ and $\gamma_{n+1} (G)=1$ since Z(G) is cyclic then for some $i$ we must have $Z(G) \le \gamma_i(G)$ 
Is there any relation to find this $i$?
I wonder how coclass of group effect upper central series and lower central series? for example if we know coclass $G$ is of coclss 2, what this tell us?

Comment: Clearly $Z(G) \le \gamma_1(G)=G$, but it is not true in general that $Z(G) \le \gamma_2(G)$.

Comment: what property $G$ must have to $Z(G)\le \gamma_2 (G)$

Comment: It is impossible to answer that without having some idea of what kind of property you are thinking of.

Comment: I added some property, I hope they are helpful.